# Compressing JSON

Tags: vb.net, json

I am saving long Json string into DB , fetching the string from Db and then serializing it for other manipulation is making it slow.

Is there any good solution to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there was told, you might need to use Documented-Oriented DB, like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

If you can't do this, please consider combined data storage: something you may store in RDBMS, something - in MongoDB.

And if it is impossible for certain reasons, please look at binary formats of JSON: [Smile](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/SmileFormat) or [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/), both of which are supported by various frameworks, such as JSON.Net (article for consideration http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/12/26/json-net-3-5-release-6-binary-json-bson-support.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way is to use a document oriented database which support json for storage. This way you can query or update part of the long json without fetching or serializing it.

Comment: thanks @medi , but cant change the DB structure as no time for migration and cant risk to have more support for the system which is running on production